# Issues are coming while running IBM Blockchain Marbles Demo

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, marble

I have run IBM marbles demo for implementing blockchain mentioned in below link: 
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles

When I have run Hyperledger Fabric and Marbles application on the same system(Ubuntu), it is working.

But when I have tried to run Hyperledger Fabric and client-side marble application in two different systems (one ubuntu and the other windows), it is not working.

Network script is running properly on Ubuntu.

And I also have changed in blockchain credential file by replacing localhost to IP address on which we need to run marbles application.

But when I am running chaincode installation script by running "node install_chaincode.js", it is giving an error as below :

```
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed error: [fcw] Failed to obtain endorsement for transaction. code=14, error: [fcw] Error in install catch block object code=14
```

Can anyone provide me the solution or any reference link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please clarify. If I understand correctly, you are running the client on a windows system and the network on an ubuntu system? Is that correct? Can you please also indicate what version of Fabric you are running? Thanks

Comment: Yes, your understanding is proper.I am using version v1.0.1 of Fabric.

I have download the code of fabric-sample from below link :
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples

Comment: You may want to update to the latest release https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v1.0.5 and be sure that the fabric-samples is current with the latest 'release' branch. It is possible that you had inconsistency between binaries and sample code and data.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Currently I have run the network on one linux host and run the client on another 2 virtual instance. So, marbles demo is working.


I have run install and instantiate chaincode scripts on one client and but when I am trying to run it on another client, it gives an error lile "Promise is rejected".

But if I simple runs 2nd client without running chaincode scripts, demo is working on both the client. Like, if I will do any transaction on one client then it also affects another client.

So, if we want to run more clients, so chaincode must installed only one client, is that correct ?

Comment: You will need to generate certificates for the new host. You cannot simply reuse another host's crypto material. As for chaincode, you need to install chaincode on each peer that will run it. You only need to instantiate the chaincode once, though (install and instantiate are separate steps).

Comment: Ok, I am using same certificates on each peer so that's why errors were coming while running install and instantiate chaincode scripts.

So, let me generate the different certificates for another clients.

Comment: Also , I have another question regarding this marbles demo that I have posted as fresh question mentioned below :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187808/where-is-the-transactions-stored-in-ibm-blockchain-marbles-demo

Can you please refer it and give an answer?