# Where is the transactions stored in IBM Blockchain Marble's Demo?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am running blockchain demo which is provided by IBM mentioned in below link :

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles

I have run Hyper ledger Fabric network on one linux system and 3 more clients on another 3 virtual instance on which my marbles client is running. It is working proper.

If we do any transactions then it will affect all the 3 client,
So, now if I want to see the all the transactions details, from where I can see it?

Is there any database or any files on client side?

Please provide me answer or reference link if any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When using the [Marbles tutorial](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles), there is a “Story Mode” option that will display more details about the transaction process.  See point 10 under the “Use Marbles” heading.

Transactions are stored on a ledger which is associated with each peer.  Refer to the Hyperledger Fabric [documentation on the ledger](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/ledger.html).  The linked [Transaction Flow](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/txflow.html) section might also be helpful.  The ledger itself is not propagated to a client-side application.  However, queries initiated from client applications can be run against the ledger to return information.

The Hyperledger Fabric [Writing Your First Application](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/write_first_app.html) documentation topic could also help to explain how querying the ledger works.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled "Story Mode", in which last step they have mentioned is   

"The block containing our transaction is sent from the orderer to our peer. Finally it is validated by the peer and then committed to the peer's ledger."

But where is peer's ledger, is there any database or json files or anything else on disc that I did not getting.

Comment: I have also read that documentation of ledger in which they have mentioned couch db database, so what is the use of "CouchDB", is it used for storing the transaction details, if yes so how to install it my linux system?

Comment: The ledger is stored on a peer's file system.  There are not human-readable files (such as JSON files) on the file system for inspecting the ledger.  Concerning a database, LevelDB is used as the default for the state database (part of the ledger) which stores the latest key values.

CouchDB is an alternative database that can be used for the state database.  Since CouchDB is a JSON document store, it provides the capability of rich queries.  The documentation section on the ledger indicates that docker containers supplied by Hyperledger Fabric can support running CouchDB.

Comment: Thank you for your response, But how to install and configure CouchDB on my linux system and how to connect it with this marbles demo application, so we can able to see all the transactions in CouchDB.

Answer (score 1):

The marbles demo starts and uses a CouchDB docker container. You might be able to query it, but I don't know how the image was built. See line 187 in docker-compose-marblesv3.yaml.

It's easy to install CouchDB. You tell the peers about their CouchDB in the core.yaml file. But I don't see anything in the docker-compose-marblesv3.yaml so it is probable set in the image.