# Querying the ledger in Hyper Ledger Fabric Network

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger

I have refereed below link for Querying into the ledger in Hyper-ledger Fabric Network :

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/write_first_app.html

In above link, they have given git-hub link in which I have done all the steps like,
 - start the network
 - run the node scripts for querying to the ledger like invoke.js, query.js

But in that scripts they have provided one example of Car, in which they called different functions for querying all car, adding car and so on.

I have also run the marbles demo mentioned in below link :
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles

In this link, they have run the same network named "fabric-samples" which I have mentioned first link of this question.

So, now I want to run queries for marbles and for that I have changed the query.js and in that I have give chaincode id as "marbles" and give function name "readMarble" and pass the marble name in argument.

And then I have node query.js so it gives an errors as below :

Store path:/home/riyasoni/riya/blockchain/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Received unknown invoke function name - 'readMarble')
    at new createStatusError (/home/riyasoni/riya/blockchain/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:65:15)
    at /home/riyasoni/riya/blockchain/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:568:15
Query has completed, checking results
error from query =  { Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Received unknown invoke function name - 'readMarble')
    at new createStatusError (/home/riyasoni/riya/blockchain/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:65:15)
    at /home/riyasoni/riya/blockchain/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:568:15
  code: 2,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'chaincode error (status: 500, message: Received unknown invoke function name - \'readMarble\')' }

So, can anyone suggest me that how can querying to ledger for marbles demo related functions and transaction?

Comment: It's because grpc updated to 1.8.4 from 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

If you look in marbles.go, lines 144 - 177, you will see a list of the available function names. readMarble is not one of them. You will also see the line 176 returning your error message.  return shim.Error("Received unknown invoke function name - '" + function + "'")

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, you can see that read Marble function is there mentioned as below:

// Handle different functions
 if function == "initMarble" { //create a new marble
  return t.initMarble(stub, args)
 }else if function == "readMarble" { //read a marble
  return t.readMarble(stub, args)
 }

But, they have given all this scripts and queries for some Cars related data.

And I want to do the queries for marbles, that's why I have changed the chaincode ID , function name and pass marbles name in argument.But it is not working.

Comment: Thank you for your faster response. You were right actually, I was calling different function which was not present in marbles.go, so now querying for marbles is working properly.

But can you tell me that where this marbles data are stored on peer in disc ?

Comment: I think that should be asked as a new question.

Comment: Yes, I have already added this question on forum mentioned in below link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187808/where-is-the-transactions-stored-in-ibm-blockchain-marbles-demo/

If you have any idea about that, then please provide your answer.

Answer (score 0):

readMarble is not a valid function. Check for correct spelling.
Also, make sure that readMarble is callable from Invoke function.